# JS/Jquery on air scheduler timeline like bbc on air schedule

Tags: javascript, jquery, schedule, timeline

I've made a planning application which look like this:
BBC Schedule:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5TTH5.jpg]
or
KBS Schedule:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XVu9J.jpg]

I found differents jquery's plugins but they're not suitable for my case. If you've got some information or plugins you know...

Regards.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

There is one, vis.js that I think that is what you are looking for